# Prove that the limit of zeroes of a non zero complex valued function is an essential singularity of the function

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Theorem : If f is a non zero complex valued function, the limit point of zeroes of f is an essential singularity of f.

I need a proof of this theorem.

Comment: please include the source which you are referring to.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}- \{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ then any limit point $a$ of its zeros is a $p_j$ (proof : if $f$ was analytic at $a$ then $f(z) = C (z-a)^k+O(z-a)^{k+1}$ woudn't vanish near $a$) and $p_j$ is an essential singularity (proof : it is an isolated singularity and it is not a pole since otherwise $1/f$ would be analytic so it wouldn't vanish near $p_j)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z_0$ is a pole of a $f$ then necessarily $|f(z)|  \to \infty$ as $z \to z_0$. [Rudin's book has a proof of this fact]. Hence a limit point of zeros cannot be a pole. It cannot be a removable singularity also so it must be an essential singularity.